# Weird bug with React updating state based on previous state

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have this useEffect hook that I created to fetch movies with pagination and render them:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMovies = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get<ResponseDataFromFetchMovies>(
          `/${selectedGenre === "My list" ? "myList" : "movies"}?skip=${
            moviesRendered.length
          }&genre=${selectedGenre === "All movies" ? "" : selectedGenre}${
            searchTitle && "&title=" + searchTitle
          }`
        );

        if (response.status === 204) {
          setTotalAmountOfMovies(0);
          return;
        }

        const newSliceOfMovies = response.data.oneSliceOfMovies;
        const totalAmount = response.data.totalAmountOfMovies;

        setMoviesRendered([...moviesRendered, ...newSliceOfMovies]);
        setTotalAmountOfMovies(totalAmount);
      } catch (error) {
        setMessageAlert(genericErrorAlert);
        setTotalAmountOfMovies(0);
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    fetchMovies();
  }, [selectedGenre, searchTitle, infiniteLoader, setMessageAlert]);
```

This implementation seems to be working fine even though I am not updating the state based on previous state properly:
`setMoviesRendered([...moviesRendered, ...newSliceOfMovies]);`

I tried changing this line to:
`setMoviesRendered((previousMovies) => [...previousMovies, ...newSliceOfMovies]);`

But when I do so it completely messes up everything and starts to present some really weird behavior like rendering the same movie multiple times and/or rendering random movies.

Can anyone tell what is happening?